# AdSense Vertical Alignment in Div

Tags: vertical-alignment, adsense

I use a responsive grid in my content that works perfectly except with my AdSense responsive unit.

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_5_of_8"><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Adsense-Responsive -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxx"
     data-ad-slot="7421734897"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></div>
  <div class="col span_3_of_8">
    <p>website text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the adsense unit on the left has a margin above it so the Ad on the Left and the Text on the right side are not vertically aligned up top. When I use this responsive code on other forms of text/images, they are always perfectly aligned. But it seems the AdSense is adding a margin above.

The css for the col is:

```
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
```

I tried playing with those margins, but nothing worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please create a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you asking to me to put live AdSense code on the fiddle?

Comment: Yes, or show your site. How are we supposed to help you if you don't?